# Select records between two columns with date and ignoring Year from date column

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, datediff

myTable with events looks like this:

```
id     |    from_date    |    to_date    
 1     |   2014-10-01    |   2015-02-20
 2     |   2014-08-25    |   2015-04-01
```

from_date and to_date are **date** columns
Year isn't important for becouse all events are every year the same time. for example between 10-01 to 02-20 every year.

I want to select all events in today so 10-22

I was trying using **DayOfYear** but without success.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DayOfYear('2014-10-22') 
BETWEEN DayOfYear(`from_date`) AND DayOfYear(`to_date`)
```

**BETWEEN** with date_format(from_date,'%m%d') doesn't work too

Any help will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse the condition when `to_date` is in the next year after `from_date`.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (YEAR(from_date) = YEAR(to_date) 
        AND DAYOFYEAR('2014-10-22') BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR(from_date) AND DAYOFYEAR(to_date))
    OR 
      (YEAR(from_date) != YEAR(to_date) 
        AND DAYOFYEAR('2014-10-22') NOT BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR(to_date) AND DAYOFYEAR(from_date))
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6e77a/7)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in your query is error and I can't find where. Please check [SQFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6e77a/1)

Comment: I had an extra parenthesis. Why couldn't you find it? Don't you have an editor that shows matching parentheses?

Comment: I was typing it in phpmyadmin thats why :/  Anyway it doesn't work. this query should return only first record [SQFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6e77a/3) but it returns all records.

Comment: You didn't copy correctly. In the second `BETWEEN` test, `to_date` has to come before `from_date`. See the updated fiddle.

Comment: It's strange because I used your demo. Anyway it works great! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: My original demo was just a single-character edit of your sqlfiddle. All I did was fix the parenthesis, I didn't notice the other problem.